# RecyclerView library to pull up and load more when reached end of list (on the top)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I faced a problem that there are a lot of libraries that provide pull down to refresh and load more from the bottom.

But I need something that I can use for my reverse RecyclerView.
I want to pull up to refresh and load more from the top of the screen.

Is there any libraries to simplify this work?

Thank you in advance!